# A property similar to arithmetical property

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

By an arithmetical ring is understood a commutative ring $R$ with 
identity for which the ideals form a distributive lattice, i.e., for  which 
$(I+J)\cap K=(I\cap K)+(J\cap K)$ for all ideals $I, J$ and $K$ of $R$. Also, a ring $R$ is called a **completely arithmetical** ring if for every ideal $I$ and every nonempty family of ideals $\{J_i\}_{i\in A}$ one has
$I +\bigcap_{i\in A}J_i=\bigcap_{i\in A}
(I+J_i)$.
I am looking for some references for studying rings with the following $X$-property, which is not equivalent to the completely arithmetical property see [1]:

> A ring $R$ has $X$-property whenever for every ideal $I$ and every nonempty family of ideals $\{J_i\}_{i\in A}$ one has
>   $I \cap(\sum_{i\in A}J_i)=\sum_{i\in A}
> (I\cap J_i)$.

[1].https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2013.804924

Comment: Doesn't the $X$-property follow from the bare arithmetical property $I \cap (J + K) = I \cap J + I \cap K$ by induction (any given element of the LHS/RHS lies in sum of finitely many ideals)?

Answer (score 2):

Let us not leave this question as unanswered:

> > A ring $R$ has the $X$-property if and only if $R$ is [arithmetical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_ring).

The proof is straightforward.